# Static vs Not Static web repositories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, asp.net-web-api, static

I recently found an excellent [tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1063/create-rest-service-using-aspnet-webapi) for web api / angular website development. I noticed while following the tutorial that some repositories are [static](https://github.com/dotnetcurry/angular-webapi-series/blob/master/ProjectTrackingServices/Models/EmployeesRepository.cs) while others are [not static](https://github.com/dotnetcurry/angular-webapi-series/blob/master/ProjectTrackingServices/Models/ProjectsRepository.cs).

**Is there any reason for a repository to be static or not static? Performance? Concurrency issues?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While people may view this as an opinion based question, there is a very real *objective* answer to the question.

Using static data contexts in *any* situation where there will be threads, multiple users, or multiple 'views' is an *extremely extremely bad idea*.

Let's take a look here:

```
public static List<Employee> InsertEmployee(Employee e)
{
    dataContext.Employees.Add(e);
    dataContext.SaveChanges();
    return GetAllEmployees();
}
```

Looks innocent enough, right? Wrong. This method will save *any change that the context detects. This includes changes made by other users and/or threads*.

For example, we're getting all the employees in the system. And we're not telling entity framework *not* to track the entities.

```
public static List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
{
    var query = from employee in dataContext.Employees
                select employee;
    return query.ToList();
}
```

So, if one thread were to load the employees, and change the name (but not save, yet), and then another page called `InsertEmployee`, the name change will also be saved.

I cannot think of a single case where a static data context isn't a terrible idea in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: I never considered that SaveChanges will affect all users if static. In certain circumstances, it probably could create a lot of headaches. Its probably safer to just make all the repositories not static.

Answer (score 1):

For no good reason.

While implementing it as a static repository he lost the power of dependency injection and unit testing while gaining no real power in exchange.